# Scrollbar loses focus when datagridview refreshs its content

Tags: c#, datagridview, focus, refresh

my DataGridView refreshes after one second its content. the refresh is triggered via a thread/invoke. when i grab the scrollbar and the refresh starts i lose the focus and i have to regrab the scrollbar again. doing that every second is quite annoying.
has anyone a hint how to do it that way i dont lose the focus? as a concrete example, like the task manager does it.

Comment: can you give some insight by using at least a dummy code.

Comment: here the code : http://pastebin.com/YCwXrJL5

Comment: Have you tried nesting the DataGridView in a Panel? You'd have to turn off scrolling on the DataGridView (ScrollBars property) and turn it on for the Panel (VScroll property).

Comment: @Jeff Mattfield Is that the only thing he would have to do? If that is NOT the case it sure would be nice to have a sample code as an answer.