# DataGridView in a Panel can't scroll

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scroll, panel

I need to have a smooth elegant scroll on my DataGridView while it is updating\work.

Because everytime i update my DataGridView, it resets Scrollbar to the top.
I found a solution to use `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` property, but then i realized that it's not enough to just save RowIndex, i need to back up my focus on scroll. I tried to Google it, and found that i need to use a Panel.

I tried, but I didn't know how to bind my DGV to Panel.
I moved it in Panel. Added in code `this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.DGV);`
and turn `DGV.ScrollBars` to `none`.
And still i don't see any scrolls on my panel, to scroll data in DGV.

Solutions I tried:

[Scrollbar loses focus when datagridview refreshs its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360914/scrollbar-loses-focus-when-datagridview-refreshs-its-content)

[Problem with DataGridView and scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140355/problem-with-datagridview-and-scroll-position)

[How can I set the position of my datagrid scrollbar in my winforms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378330/how-can-i-set-the-position-of-my-datagrid-scrollbar-in-my-winforms-app)

Answer (score 0):

`"I need to have a smooth elegant scroll on my DataGridView while it is updating\work".`

VirtualizationStackPanel / VirtualizationPanel would helps to load items in a datagrid based on the scroll amount.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingpanel(v=vs.90).aspx

`still i don't see any scrolls on my panel, to scroll data in DGV`

`DGV.ScrollBars` to `none` will disable the grid scrollbars. You can try insert a `ScrollViewer` control outside to `Panel`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665.aspx

Comment: can you, please, show some code sample. i can't understand how to bind it to DGV.

Comment: i use windows forms, not WPF