# Datagridview ScrollBar Looses it's focus after binding reset

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a DataGridView, which I need to update the content every 3 seconds. I am able to save the DGV position with this code:

```
    private void UpdateBindings()
    {
        int _ScrollPosition = MonitorGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;

        _BS.ResetBindings(false); // _BS = BindingSource
        if (_ScrollPosition > -1)
        {
            MonitorGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = _ScrollPosition;
        }
    }
```

This code works perfect, however, the ONLY problem I am facing is that I lose the FOCUS on my scrollbar after every reset. Let's say I am scrolling to the bottom, and it updates, I need to regrab the scrollbar again. This is very annoying.

My question is exactly same as this one: [Scrollbar loses focus when datagridview refreshs its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360914/scrollbar-loses-focus-when-datagridview-refreshs-its-content)

However, I am not able to find the answer or figure out a way for me to solve this.

Can anyone please point me to the correct way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by creating a new vScrollBar and programatically changing the current row value of DataGridView.

```
    private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue > -1 && e.NewValue < MonitorGridView.Rows.Count)
        {
            MonitorGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = e.NewValue;
        }
    }
```